# How to fix setState ansync error in react snake game

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, setstate

I build a react snake game and I recognized an error. When I move the snake with `onkeydown()`, in some cases I get an error that shouldn't be happened.

It's happening when the snake length bigger than 2 and user click on an arrow key and then, very quickly, click on the opposite key in relation to the original direction.

For example: user move to the left and then click --> down --> right. The snake should move like a quick "U-turn" but instead of it moves just to right (skipping down key). And because the snake direction is to the left, in the right there is the snake body. Therefor, instead of move U-turn, the game failed because the snake collides itself.

I want to mention that I use if statement (in `ChangeDirection()`) to avoid cases that when snake direction is to the left, it moves to the right immediately, in order to avoid snake collides itself. But in this case the user overrides this restriction by clicking quickly down --> right.

Why this is happaned? This is because setState is async function? How can I solve this problem?

You can see the project here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-benz-jg9xh

Comment: Please refer to [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), or create a minimal example in a sandbox-like [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io). You supposing that people will clone your repo and try to replicate the problem, it's possible, but there is a low chance that someone will really do it.

Comment: @DennisVash You right! I do as you said. Please review the project and help me. https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-benz-jg9xh

Comment: I haven't gone through your codebase but it looks it breaking on logic you have to debug it all the way, cause pressing right and down when a snake is going top it means your snake should start moving bottom but it crushes put some checker and try finding the bug